# Loading the Question Failed

Tags: bug, android-app

I just posted a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198170/test-test-test-test) from android app and now trying to view it but it says "Loading the Question Failed".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Post a Question from Android app
2. Now ask some one to comment on your question. (So that it can appear in your feed screen, Unfortunately in my case [Robert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198170/test-test-test-test?noredirect=1#comment627767_198170) did the job :) )
3. Delete Question from web (Oh yeh, there is no facility in app to delete question yet)
4. Do pull to refresh in Feed screen of android app.
5. Now click on that question/comment feed and get question loading failed dialog!

Comment: Edited the other question that was mentioned in the comments and marked this as a duplicate of it. The issue here is that the feed doesn't know when a post is deleted or not, which it should.